# conversion of date and time to one number Bash Programming

Tags: shell

input file contains

```
2012-12-23 23:59:59
```

I have to first convert time into sec and then combine with date ( addition of date as a decimal to time)

```
time (sec) = 23*3600 + 59*60 + 59 = 86400
```

date .23 ( take date only)

output should be `86400.23`

Friends please help me. I am not able to get this working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See the following `bash` code :

```
d='2012-12-23 23:59:59'
IFS=: read h m s <<< "$d"
day=${d% *}; day=${day##*-}
echo $(( (${h#* } * 3600) + (m * 60) + s)).$day
```

Or with `awk` :

```
d='2012-12-23 23:59:59'
read day hour min sec < <(awk -F'[ :-]' '{print $3, $4, $5, $6}' <<< "$d")
echo $(( (hour * 3600) + (min * 60) + sec)).$day
```

Or simply :

```
 echo '2012-12-23 23:59:59' | awk -F'[ :-]' '{print ($4*3600)+($5*60)+$6"."$3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `date` command to validate/format the input:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read datetime
date=$(date --date="$datetime" +%d)
time=$(date --date="$datetime" +"1970-01-01 %H:%M:%S UTC")
echo $(date --date="$time" +%s).$date
# -> 86399.23
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/2L76G)